# PHP detect if in subdirectory

Tags: php

I want to determine if the PHP file I am on `install.php` is in a subdomain/subdirectory (basically not at domain.com/install.php).

### Found solution to my problems

see below

Comment: Whats with the random downvotes?

Comment: Not my downvote(s), but I see at least two problems: you seem to be asking for a prebuilt script, without having made any apparent effort on your own (if you have, talk about it!), and your first paragraph is one long, hard-to-read sentence.

Comment: I see you added your attempt - what about it is giving you trouble?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta didn't post my version originally because I was having issues getting the code to block. All they needed to do was give me like 40 seconds or so.

Comment: You should have waited to post your question. Anyway, you've regained your points, so it's all good.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Definitely leaned my lesson about that.

Comment: Why downvote? This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear and not useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax error is because you are missing the `;` at the end of `$scriptname="install.php"`.

Your method looks like it should work okay.

Another way you could determine if the file is installed at the domain root instead of a folder or subdomain would be something like this:

```
function subdomboolcheck()
{
    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $filePath = dirname(__FILE__);

    if ($root == $filePath) {
        return false; // installed in the root
    } else {
        return true;  // installed in a subfolder or subdomain
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])` to get the directory portion of the URI.

Comment: I've been trying to make a router dynamically work with and without subdirs (end user's choice) and I've played around with so many things, `REQUEST_URI`, `__DIR__`, and all sorts with and without `basename()`, `dirname()`, then I found this. Thanks Bamar! Sensible and simple answer yet had no votes. +1 (should be noted to check if value exists, however, as it's not guaranteed these are always set by the server)

Answer (score 0):

To scan specific directories:

```
if(file_exists('/subdir/install.php')) {
    // it exists there
} elseif(file_exists('/subdir2/install.php')) {
    // it exists there
} else {
    // it's not in these directories
}
```

To scan all directories:

```
$files = glob('/*');

foreach($files as $file) {
 //check to see if the file is a folder/directory
    if(is_dir($file)) {
        if(file_exists($file . 'install.php')) {
            // it was found   
        } else {
            // it was not found
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer got downvoted literally the millisecond it was posted?

Comment: I am distributing this application. So I do not know where it will be.

Comment: Edited answer to provide a more flexible option as well as a directed/specific option.

Comment: @Chris What about the code I am thinking about currently in the edited question?

Comment: The OP talks about an url, you about paths within the filesystem. Additional it seems you don't know, what `/` at the beginning of a path means.

Comment: @ChrisMirno using `/` will go to the root directory regardless of the domain or subdomain. So, `/images` will always point to the images directory in the root. I would recommend using that rather than `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` because an internal script doesn't need to make an HTTP request back to its own server.

Comment: I would also downvote this answer if I could, because it's pretty dumb to traverse the whole file system every time someone accesses the script. That could take minutes and matters would get worse, if there are mounted network shares. Everything beyond 2-5 seconds is inacceptable for real world applications. Also, what if there are multiple files named 'install.php'? And lastly - hardcoded directory names? are you serious?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

See [PHP $_SERVER Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: It won't work for sub.example.com/install.php, you have to check both $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: I think you should put the code that checks the $_server['REQUEST_URI'] in place of the comment `// continue` (but that depends on what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($handle = opendir('directory/subdirectory/')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if (strpos($entry, '.php') !== false) {
          echo $entry."<br>";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain your answer with some brief sentences. Like where was mistake made or why to use your answer.

Comment: Is this even an attempt at answering the question?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not 100% complete because it hasn't been tested on all server environments, but I can confirm this will work if using the embedded PHP web engin or using an apache server with a symlinked web folder.  The function returns the subfolder in the form /folder because that is what I needed.  If someone can check Nginx it will help a lot.  Notice the use of CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT vs DOCUMENT_ROOT && SCRIPT_NAME vs REQUEST_URI because that could mean a router URL vs actual live file. To use as per the asked question you could say

```
If (!empty(getSubFolder())) {
  //Do some stuff here
}
```

```
/**
     * Logic to determine the subfolder - result must be /folder
     */
    function getSubFolder() {

        //Evaluate DOCUMENT_ROOT && CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT
        $documentRoot = "";
        if (isset($_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"])) {
            $documentRoot = $_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
        } else
            if (isset($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])) {
                $documentRoot = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
            }
            $scriptName = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];



            //echo str_replace($documentRoot, "", $scriptName);
            $subFolder = dirname( str_replace($documentRoot, "", $scriptName));

            if ($subFolder === "/" || (str_replace($documentRoot, "", $scriptName) === $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] && $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] === $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
                $subFolder = null;
            }

            return $subFolder;
    }
```